# Undeclared Identifier-Declarations Present In Header, But Unidentified In Class Source

Tags: c++, header, identifier, undeclared-identifier

So, I'm having what is likely a pretty simple problem, but I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

I have a C++ class called "Game" consisting of a class declaration in Game.h
and a source definition in Game.cpp.

I have included "Game.h" in my "Game.cpp", but for some reason Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognize the class declarations within Game.h.

I'd appreciate any help I could get trying to figure out why this is the case, and why I am getting the following errors:
`'MyCharacter' : undeclared identifier` and `'HandleKeyPressed' : identifier not found`.

Game.h:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma once
#ifndef Game_Header
#define Game_Header


#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include "Character.h"
#include "FloorPlatform.h"

class Game
{
public:
        Game();
        ~Game();
        int Run();
        void HandleKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key);
        Character MyCharacter;
};

#endif // !Game_Header
```

### Abridged Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"


Game::Game()
{
}


Game::~Game()
{
}

int Run(){
        sf::RenderWindow MainGameWindow(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "A Test Game");

        //Start Game Loop
        while (MainGameWindow.isOpen()){
                while (MainGameWindow.pollEvent(event)){
                        //Handle some other events here...
                        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed){
                                HandleKeyPressed(event.key.code);
                        }
                }


                MainGameWindow.clear(sf::Color::White);

                MyCharacter.Instance.Circle.setPosition(MyCharacter.PlayerLocation);
                MainGameWindow.draw(MyCharacter.Instance.Circle);
                MainGameWindow.display();

        }

        return 0;
}

void HandleKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key PressedKey){
        switch (PressedKey)
        {
        case sf::Keyboard::A:
             MyCharacter.PlayerLocation.x -= 16;
        break;

        }
}
```

Full code can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/x6KhDxgL

Thanks in advance for any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int Game::Run()
```

instead of

```
int Run()
```

in Game.cpp, the same for `HandleKeyPressed`, because it's the method of the `Game` class. Depending on your `Character.h` you may need to initialize `MyCharacter`, too.

Comment: Wow... I feel like an idiot. So, just changing the methods to the Game namespace fixed the problem. Why does not declaring the namespace cause the other members of the class to be unrecognized? Can anyone explain this?   Also, for clarity: I changed int Run() and void HandleKeyPressed to int Game::Run() and void Game::HandleKeyPressed as suggested.

Comment: Because you are declaring the method definitions outside the class definition. If you wrote whole methods in `Game` definition in your `Game.h`, it probably will be ok. Since you are doing it outside the class, you need to use the `::` (scope operator). And also `#inlude "Game.h"` is *not* the same as using the namespace.

Comment: Ah... That clears it up a little, but, why does this affect the 'MyCharacter' identifier? I would think that because the identifier is declared in Game.h, that it should be usable throughout Game.cpp. I appreciate the help. I'm glad my stuff works, I'm just really trying to understand this a bit better, so I don't have to ask as many silly questions in the future. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's like declaring `int a` - you aren't assigning any value to `MyCharacter` parts. However, I am just guessing at this part, since I can't run whole your code (including your header files). If this is the problem, give it values in your `Game` constructor. Also, if this answer helps you, please mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
void HandleKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key PressedKey){
```

In Game.cpp should be

```
void Game::HandleKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key PressedKey){
```

Same for int run()